# Flask(Gunicorn) doesn't serve app after multiple refresh

Tags: python, flask, video-streaming, gunicorn

I am testing a flask web app which is supposed to show a mjpeg video stream on a web page.

The client side uses a **img** tab with **src=/video_src**.
On the server side I am using a handler for /video_src that returns multipart data from a generator function

```
server = Flask(__name__)
camera = Camera("path to network camera stream") # global camera object instantiated once 

@server.route("/video_src")
def video_src():
    return Response(camera.gen(), mimetype="multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame")

# gen function from camera class. The self.frame value is the actual jpeg bytes. It is calculated
# in a separate thread and kept updated to the latest frame by the camera class.
    def gen(self):
        while True:
            print(f"id: {threading.get_ident()}")
            yield (
                b"--frame\r\n"
                b"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" + self.frame + b"\r\n\r\n"
            )
            time.sleep(0.25)
```

I am using gunicorn to run the app:

```
gunicorn --threads 3 --workers 1 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 app:server
```

Everything works fine when the app is accessed for the first time in the browser. I can see in the logs the **gen()** function being called with a single thread id repeatedly at 0.25 sec interval. After 1st refresh, the site again loads fine and I see 2 different interspersed thread ids from the generate function. After a while, the old thread id stops printing and only the new thread id print continues. The same thing happens on 2nd refresh but on 3rd refresh the site stops loading. The logs from **gen()** also stops, but from other logs it seems the app itself is  fine. Only after 15mins do I see an error and now the site can load again

```
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

If I increase the gunicorn threads I can do the refresh more times before the site stops to load.
So it's as if the gunicorn threads are being depleted but never being recycled. What could be the reason/fix here, perhaps a gunicorn configuration value change is needed?

**EDIT**
This seems to work on my x86_64 Mac but not on aarch64 Rpi. Both machines are using same version of Flask(3.0.0) and Werkzeug(3.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

Could not figure out the underlying issue, but was able to hack it with:

```py
from flask import Flask, Response, stream_with_context, request

def frame_generator(input_stream):
    try:
        while True:
            if input_stream.read() is not None:
                raise GeneratorExit
            yield (
                b"--frame\r\n"
                b"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" + camera.get_frame() + b"\r\n\r\n"
            )
            time.sleep(0.25)
    except GeneratorExit:
        logger.info("Exiting gen")

@server.route("/video_src")
def video_src():
    """Note: Using input_stream is a hack, since when the browser closes or refreshes, the generator should be closed
    and the thread running it released. This works on x86_64 Mac but on aarch64 Rpi this doesn't seem to happen. Thus
    on Rpi, the thread is never released and all threads are consumed on reloads/refreshes. But this hack does not work
    when using gunicorn so python should be used directly to run"""
    stream = request.input_stream
    os.set_blocking(stream.fileno(), False)
    frames = frame_generator(stream)
    return Response(stream_with_context(frames), mimetype="multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame")
```